# Kapt not processing micronaut-predator-processor

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, kapt

I am trying to use the new Predator JPA/JDBC library from Micronaut.
I wish to use the JDBC integration rather than JPA.

I am having a couple of issues however, the documentation says to include:

`annotationProcessor 'io.micronaut.data:micronaut-predator-processor:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'`

Which I have done so, but the kapt section of the build fails with the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationMetadata.enumValue(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;`

I am using micronaut 1.1.4 on JVM 12.0.1

If I replace `kapt` with `annotationProcessor`, the build completes fine, however I get a runtime issue:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micronaut.data.exceptions.DataAccessException`

Which is odd as I seem to be able to use `kapt/annotationProcessor` interchangeable for micronaut security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get this to work for the micronaut 1.2.0 RC2 by updating the BOM entry:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:1.2.0.RC2'
    }
}
```

This seems to allow all the annotation processing etc to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when running tests from Intellij Idea. But they passed when run through gradle.

If you are using Intellij Idea and facing this issue, try following options in the sequence:

1. Invalidate Idea cache and restart
2. Enable Annotation Processing
3. Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle. This setting had got reset to Idea when I upgraded my Intellij version.

Comment: As this was a micronaut project I had number 2, but didnt consider 1.  Worth keeping in mind.